# Carousel does not cycle under bootstrap-v3.3.5

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am facing almost the same issue as the one previously reported and fixed in [#3528](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3528): carousel does not cycle.

I tried all the plausible solutions discussed under [#3528](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/3528), but none worked. The following is my config code, and please let me know what is going wrong:

JAVA SCRIPT:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $('#ck-carousel').carousel({
             interval: 2000,
             cycle: true,
             pause: 'none'
         })
    });    
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="ck-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="2000">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="active item">
            <img src="/assets/images/growth.jpg" alt="...">
            <mc-signup-growth> </mc-signup-growth>
        </div>

        <div class="item">
            <img src="/assets/images/beauty.jpg" alt="...">
            <mc-signup-beauty> </mc-signup-beauty>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#ck-carousel" role="button" data-slide="prev"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#ck-carousel" role="button" data-slide="next"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span> </a>

    </div>
```

Comment: Please, provide jsfiddle.

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine other then the fact that you're using data-attributes and using JS together. You only need one or the other.

Comment: Thanks, Vanburen. I have tried using only one, but it did not help.